# How to search a term within old commit content, showing it within context?

Tags: git, grep, commit

To search within commits text, we use `git log -G SEARCHTERM`. This lists the commit hash and commit message.

Is there a way to show results like with grep, showing the `SEARCHTERM` within context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pretty close thing is to add `-p` :

```
git log -p -G SEARCHTERM
```

When you combine `-p` with `-G`, `git` will only display the files where `SEARCHTERM` was found.

For those files, it will display the complete diff though, rather than just the chunks where `SEARCHTERM` appeared.

Comment: Great, thanks! I couldn't manage to find this anywhere. How did you find this?

Comment: I thought I read it in `git help log`, but I can't find the reference. Likewise : `--name-status` and `--name-only` will limit the list of files to only ones which are involved in the `-G` or `-S` pickaxe option, but I can't find the mention in the documentation at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, add the `-p` option.

See https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_diff_formatting:

> By default, `git log` does not generate any diff output. The options
> below can be used to show the changes made by each commit.
>
> […]
>
> ```
> -p
> -u
> --patch
> ```
>
> Generate patch (see section on generating patches).

Which refers to https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_generating_patch_text_with_p

Comment: Thanks, however the syntax git log -p <searchterm> does not work.

Comment: Of course not, but `git log -G <searchterm> -p` does.